# Borrow checker complains for closure inside loop if type not provided explicitly

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have this code, for which borrow checker shows error:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=55d050b6f25410ce0e17ef9e844b048d

```
fn f1(v: &str) {
}

fn main() {
    let c = |v| f1(v);
    for _ in 0..1 {
        let s = String::new();
        c(&s);
    }
}
```

```
   |
10 |         c(&s);
   |         - ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         |
   |         borrow later used here
11 |     }
   |     - `s` dropped here while still borrowed
```

But if I add explicit type to closure, code compiles `let c = |v: &str| f1(v);`

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=54ca20dff5bdf1831ec705481e4936bb

Can someone explain why it works in second case and not in first, as I understand rust correctly infers same type in first example (as it works if I run closure outside of loop)?

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug. Opened [an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76627) for the same.

Comment: [One bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76627) plus [another one](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25860) equals a [solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8566ffa5d9aaaf5925e58c56585decaa). SCNR.

Answer (score -1):

`&str` is not same `&String`

`borrowed value does not live long enough`

`&str` have a static lifetime which means is guaranteed to be valid for the duration of the entire program.

But ref String(`&s`) only lives inside the loop iteration, and then it dies. A variable only lives as long as its code block.

For example, without loop, it's compile normally:

```rust
fn main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
     let c = |v| f1(v);                                                                                                                                                                                      
     let s = String::new();                                                                                                                                                                                              
     c(&s);                                                                                                                                                                                        
}
```

If you want, you can pass the ownership of string variable to `c` function, its make your string live after iteration.

```rust
fn f1(v: &str) {
}

fn main() {
    let c = |v:String| f1(&v);
    for _ in 0..1 {
        let s = String::new();
        c(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: This... does not answer the question.

Comment: Please, let me know why.... because the compilers not speak about wrong infers... this speak about "not live long enough"....

Comment: this is a correct explanation.